# what's the meaning of 'admin' OR 1=1 -- '

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection, cracking

The following query return all the passwords in the table tbl_user but I can not understand why this is happening.

```
SELECT password FROM tbl_users WHERE name = 'admin' OR 1=1 -- '
```

Please help me to understand this part of the query: 'admin' OR 1=1 -- '

Can you introduce other threats like this (website, book, etc)?

Comment: That is a classical SQL injection. It returns the users where the name is `admin` *OR* where 1=1 (since 1 is indeed 1 every record will match). The `--` just makes sure eveyrthing after it is seen as a comment

Comment: You can remove 1=1 as it does nothing

Comment: @Gadgetster what do you mean?

Comment: 1 always equals 1 so what's the point of writing it.. if it was id = 1 that would make more sense as he would be looking through it

Comment: That's the entire point @Gadgetster. It certainly does something. ;-)

Comment: @Gadgetster it does quite the opposite of nothing

Comment: Adding an `OR True` to the end of SQL is a way of ensuring a response comes back from some flavors of SQL servers, even if there are no records found.  Commonly it would be used in a loop, so step 1 - make that query, step 2 - iterate over the rows.  If there are no records returned, the loop never runs.

Comment: @PeeHaa thanks a lot, can you tell me what's the meaning of single quote after -- ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a classic SQL injection.

See this fiddle while I explain it: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d12901/4)

In this example, there are 5 users being added to the table. Your query is then run. The expected result would be to return the password value for the `admin` user only.

However, by adding `1=1`, which is a true statement, all passwords are returned.

Another way to help visualize this, is to add parenthesis so that you can see how everything is evaluated.

```
SELECT pass FROM users WHERE (user_name = 'admin')              OR (1=1) -- '
                                 ^ Pulls only the admin user        ^ Pulls everything because 1=1
```

So, we are selecting the password from the table where the user name is `admin`. We are also pulling the password from the table where ever 1=1 - which is always true. Each row is evaluated to true, thus all passwords are returned.

The final `-- '` is used to comment out the rest of your query.

```
SELECT pass from users WHERE user_name = 'admin' or (1=1) -- 'and permission='superadmin'
```

Normally, (if the `1=1` hadn't been injected), you'd pull the password for the user with user_name of admin and superadmin permissions. You've now commented that out, and it isn't executed. This is how the entire table of passwords can be returned.

Comment: Very well put, not only the logical part - I think I did this well enough - but how this exploit changes the intend of a query and how it could be extended.

Answer (score 5):

The result of a logical `OR` is as following:

```
a     | b     | a OR b
-----------------------
false | false | false
false | true  | true
true  | false | true
true  | true  | true
```

The result of a OR b evaluates to true, if one of the operands is true.

```
1 = 1 evaluates to true
```

=>

```
(any expression) OR 1 = 1 evaluates to true
```

=>

```
name = 'admin' OR 1 = 1
```

evaluates to true for every row of your table

Result:

```
SELECT password FROM tbl_users WHERE name = 'admin' OR 1=1 -- '
```

will return the passwords for all users, not only for admin, because as stated by PeeHaa

```
--
```

is the begin of a sql comment.

Comment: but this is the same as `SELECT password FROM tbl_users`, so for what reason `where` statement uses at all?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possible confusions I can imagine you experiencing here. The first is, as others have mentioned, `expr1 OR expr2` returns true whenever *either* `expr1` or `expr2` is true. Since `1=1` is always true, your `WHERE` statement will be true for every record in the table.

The second thing you might be confused about is that last `-- '` in the query. The `--` is the SQL equivalent of `//` in PHP; it indicates that the rest of the line is a comment and should be ignored. So the SQL interpreter is only reading `SELECT password FROM tbl_users WHERE name = 'admin' OR 1=1` and ignoring the rest of the line, which is why that trailing single quote isn't causing a syntax error.

The only security risk here is if you are passing unescaped user input to SQL. Always escape any user input with [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or an equivalent function before using it in an SQL query.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, parameterized queries are generally a better practice than escaping each input element manually. PHP's [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) extension is a good place to start with this approach.

Comment: IMO, it is better to use parameterisation than escaping and concatenation - the latter should only be used for things that cannot be parameterised, like column names.

Comment: @halfer I agree, parameterisation is better than escaping + concatenation as a coding practice because it is harder to make mistakes. I'll edit a reference to it into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The last part `-- '` is comment, so MySQL doesn't care. So we have no left

```
SELECT password FROM tbl_users WHERE name = 'admin' OR 1=1
```

In this query `1=1` is true because 1 is the same is 1. It could be here of course another true expressions as for example `2=2` or `'a'='a'` - the result will be always the same.

So your query could look like this:

```
SELECT password FROM tbl_users WHERE name = 'admin' OR true
```

Operator `OR` works this way that if any of conditions is true it means that the whole expression is true. In expression `name = 'admin' OR true` one expression is true (true is true) so this whole expressions is `true`

So the query now could be

```
SELECT password FROM tbl_users WHERE true
```

Now if we look at WHERE part we have `WHERE true`. It means de facto there is no condition, so we can change query into:

```
SELECT password FROM tbl_users
```

So as you see your query simple get column `password` for each records in your table (probably for all users)

Comment: Excuse me, could you help me why following query not working? `SELECT name FROM list WHERE name = true -- '`

Comment: @Daniyal, if you have a problem, please always explain what happens (error? nothing? crash? etc). In this case it is likely that you are comparing a string column with a boolean constant.

Comment: @halfer Thanks a lot MR @Marrcin, excuse me, could you help me why following query returned an empty result set? `SELECT name FROM list WHERE name = true -- '`

Comment: @Daniyal Look at the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/logical-operators.html): _In SQL, all logical operators evaluate to TRUE, FALSE, or NULL (UNKNOWN). In MySQL, these are implemented as 1 (TRUE), 0 (FALSE), and NULL._ So you've got the same as `SELECT name FROM list WHERE name = 1` No one has this name, so no result.

Comment: @Daniyal: that would be an expected result. You have no rows where that column is equal to boolean true, since it is a string. The `--'` at the end does nothing in this case - in your original post it has the effect of hiding the remainder of the original author's query, but that does not apply here.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for 'AND' instead of 'OR'

'OR' means that one of the conditions (WHERE name = 'admin' OR 1=1) must be true, and in this case, it is returning everything that has name equal to 'admin', or that has 1 equal to 1.

Try using this instead:

```
SELECT password FROM tbl_users WHERE name = 'admin' AND 1=1
```

Comment: The query is indeed not what the original author intended - it is a popular cracking syntax intended to return rows in all circumstances, taking advantage of a SQL injection vulnerability. In that context, the `OR` form is what the cracker would want.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry I am new to this stuff, just tried to help out from the little I know. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: No worries. You'd be right if the `1=1` _preceded_ the rest of the `WHERE` clause - having one permanent clause with a number of optional ones is popular for query builder libraries. This is because it simplifies the additional syntax - all new clauses are in the form `AND (clause)`.